# Get Generic arguments type of anonymous type in Roslyn assembly

Tags: c#, generics, anonymous-types, roslyn

Suppose that you have the next code:

```
        var house = new {Color = "White", Area = 150};
        var typeHouse = house.GetType();
        var argumentTypes = typeHouse.GetGenericArguments();
```

The *argumentTypes* array have two types : string and int... It's ok :)

But if I have the next code using Roslyn compiler:

```
            var tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
            namespace TestRoslyn {
                public class MyClass {
                    public void GetHouse(){
                        var house = new {Color = 'W', Area = 150};
                    }
                }
            }");

        byte[] assembly;
        var compiler = Compilation.Create("Test", new CompilationOptions(outputKind: OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
                                                                 usings: new[] { "System" }))
            .AddSyntaxTrees(tree)
            .AddReferences(new MetadataFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var result = compiler.Emit(stream);
            if (!result.Success)
                throw new Exception("You have an error! :( ");
            assembly = stream.ToArray();
        }
        Type[] types = Assembly.Load(assembly).GetTypes();
        var argumentTypes = types[0].GetGenericArguments(); //types [0] returns the <>f__AnonymousType
```

Then the *argumentTypes* array shows two generic types like "Color j_*TPar" and "Area j*_TPar"... :(

My questions is: Why in the Roslyn example I can't get the correct argument types from Anonymous type?

How to get the "correct" argument types?

Comment: Perhaps this is because they are dynamically typed, and the compiler is unable to infer their type indirectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would be clearer if I asked the same question as you did, but used `List<T>` instead of the anomous type:

> If I do `new List<int>().GetType().GetGenericArguments()`, I'm getting `int` as I expect. But if I look at the `List` type in mscorlib, it shows the generic type `T`, not `int`. Why?

Do you see the difference? In the first case, you have a *constructed type* (e.g. `List<int>`). But when you look at the assembly, you will see only the *generic type definition* (e.g. `List<T>`). The constructed type is created only when you actualy instatiate the generic type definition with some generic parameters.

If you're interested in knowing why are all anomous types generic at all, read [Eric Lippert's article *Why are anonymous types generic?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/12/20/why-are-anonymous-types-generic.aspx)

Comment: Umm Ok, I understand it now:) thanks for your answer and the link reference.